# Use of "There has been"

Tags: sentence-construction

Can I use "There has been" in the way that I have used in the following sentences: I've tried to use it in the sentences below:

1. There has been a mistake in my Writing.
2. There has been a serious discussion at my home.
3. There has been a accident on the way to school.
4. There has been a dangerous misunderstanding between us.

Am i correct here to use the phrase "There has been" in the sentences above?

Or there is different usage of this phrase ?

Comment: What do you want to imply?

Comment: Cardinal@ I want to learn the usage of "There has been". So, I've tryed to use it in sentences. So, is there any different kind of usage of " There has been" ? Or is it correct?

Answer (score 1):

All four are grammatically correct, as long as you don't specify when each event happened.

> 2. There **has been** a serious discussion at home.

Is grammatically correct.

> **Yesterday**, there has been a serious discussion at home.

Isn't. Rather, you would write/say:

> **Yesterday**, there **was** a serious discussion at home.

---

In all these cases, the present perfect is used to emphasize on the **result**. For example, take the sentence #3. You could use either the simple past or the present perfect.

> There **was** an accident on the way to school.

Is a casual and descriptive way to say that an accident happened, simply.

> There **has been** an accident on the way to school.

Is used to emphasize on the result of this accident. For example, it could be an excuse for you being late.

Comment: Madward@ sir, are my sentences above grammatically correct? Or I've missed something

Comment: @yubrajsharma: Edited my first sentence, yes they are.